# Identifier expected, Array bounds cannot appear in type specifer

Tags: database, vb.net

```
Imports.system
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:  \repos\LEARN WITH MUZII\LEARN WITH MUZII\DATA LOGIN.accdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim query As String = "select * from Table1 where username=@user and password=@pass"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand(query,con)
        cmd.Parameter.Addwithvalue("@user", userTextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameter.Addwithvalue("@pass", passTextBox2.Text)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successfully", "Sucess", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles passTextBox2.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles userTextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub
End Class
```

I try to connect with database
When I Am Run this Code two error comes Identifier expected, Array bounds cannot appear in type specifer

Comment: _cmd.Parameter_ should be _cmd.Parameters_

Comment: From the "LEARN WITH MUZII" in the path, you may want to know about [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](https://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: And also [Secure Salted Password Hashing - How to do it Properly](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).

Comment: Another one: it is necessary to dispose of the SqlConnection immediately after use, as shown in the documentation at [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection) (you may need to change it to show VB insted of C# by using the dropdown near the top-right of that page).

Comment: never never **NEVER** store passwords in plain text, not even for practice/learning/proof-of-concept work. You store a cryptographic (not md5) salted _hash_ of the password, and when someone logs in you compare hashes

Answer (score 1):

- The code needs to create a **`New`** `OleDbCommand`.
- `cmd.Parameter.` needs to be `cmd.Parameters.`.

If you set [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects) then Visual Studio can point out problems like that for you, or at least show you that something is wrong with what it puts a squiggly line under.

Using *some* of what I mentioned in comments, I think the following would be a better direction for your code:

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1

    ' Declare the connection string in just one place so it is easy to change it.
    ' Use quotes around the path in case there are spaces in it.
    Public Const CONNSTR As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""D:\repos\LEARN WITH MUZII\LEARN WITH MUZII\DATA LOGIN.accdb"""

    Function AreCredentialsValid(username As String, password As String) As Boolean
        'TODO: Add password hashing  - see https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm .

        ' It is only necessary to check if the data was matched, no need to return all the data.
        ' Put this variable declaration early so it it easy to find, in case it needs to be adjusted.
        Dim query As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table1] WHERE [username] = @user AND [password] = @pass"

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(CONNSTR)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, conn)
                'TODO: Use the correct OleDbType to match the column data type in the database.
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@user", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Value = username})
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@pass", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Value = password})

                conn.Open()
                Dim nUsers = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

                ' If nUsers = 0 then there were no matches,
                ' if nUsers > 1 Then there are two or more of the same so there is an error which must be corrected.
                Return nUsers = 1

            End Using
        End Using

    End Function

    Private Sub bnLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnLogin.Click
        Dim loginSuccessful = AreCredentialsValid(tbUser.Text, tbPassword.Text)

        If loginSuccessful Then
            MessageBox.Show("Login Successful", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Login Failed", "Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Please try to use meaningful names for the controls as otherwise it is easy to make mistakes.